# how to make carousel slider fit to course section height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, slider

I am building a new website which has carousel slider in one of its section, and want to fit that slider in that section. How can i do to set my slider so that it would fit that section area and still responsive ?

Running Bootstrap 4.3.1 and JQuery 3.4.1. In the past i've tried to change the slider css which is size to percent (%) but the slider hight still doesn't fit the section

index.html

```
<div id="course" class="offset">
  <div class="col-12 narrow text-center">
    <h1>Rental Bachtiar Medan Hehe</h1>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="course-class">
           <iframe marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="sliderCarousel.html" seamless></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="course-class">
            <h3>Custom Animation</h3>
            <p>Animate.css and Waypoints.js allow for smooth animations scrolling down the site.</p>
         </div>
      </div>

    </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

sliderCarousel.html

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=17MKwEHxWd-OCPx9P2LsTBBR0kNR__aCe" alt="Gambar - 1" >
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Slide 1</h3>
        <p>Deskripsi Slide 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1m3O0HLyKQPO-MOFcSNtP4EqpenycEQaC" alt="Gambar - 2" >
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 2</h3>
          <p>Deskripsi Slide 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NSeFxs2MXhLfCU14qtqnRWce8LPJC6bR" alt="Gambar - 3" >
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Slide 3</h3>
        <p>Deskripsi Slide 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <div class="control-prev">

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

and the rest of my css about that section. style.css

```
/*---------- COURSE SECTION ------------*/

#course .narrow{
  width: 90%;/*75%*/
  margin: 3.5rem auto;/*1.5rem*/
  padding-top: .2rem;
}


.narrow h1{
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.btn-secondary{
  border-width: medium;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: .6rem 1.2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-color: #1EBBAE;
  background-color: #1EBBAE;
  color: white;
}
.btn-secondary:hover, 
.btn-secondary:focus{
  border-color: #189582;
  background-color: #189582;
  color: white;
}
.course-class h3{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: .4rem;
  text-align: left;
}
.course-class p{
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

/*---------------------- iframe Section-----------------------------*/
iframe[seamless] {
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I expect the output of index.html at course section showing slider that fit with its section height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

Add Container-fluid if you want to show for full screen, and make sure your Image size are same

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
          <h1>Rental Bachtiar Medan Hehe</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="course-class">
          <div class="bd-example">
            <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img src="https://www.15five.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/communication-technology-1280x700.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img src="https://digitalsocial.eu/images/upload/2016/12/rideaustin-donations-rideshare-taxi-ban.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img src="https://reformedperspective.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/familytechnology.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="course-class">
          <h3>Custom Animation</h3>
          <p>Animate.css and Waypoints.js allow for smooth animations scrolling down the site.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Should we set the image height to 580px sir in order to fit that section ?

Comment: Tell me what is the width and height of your image?

Comment: 1280px width and 700px height sir

Comment: By the way our new slider also still remain a lot of space between slider to lower part of course section sir, i have set 'margin-bottom: 0px;' but still doesn't conforms to lower part of course section.
Please help me sir

Comment: Use complete bootstrap carousel instead of iframe.

Comment: I've updated code according to your image size. take look at it

Comment: if we put complete bootstrap carousel in that section, the code will looks like so long.thats why i put it in another html file.

Comment: I've fixed this issue when my site in desktop mode sir. but haven't yet in mobile mode. when i shrink the window there is a lot space between "slider" and "h3" text sir. Is that because i put the slider inside the "iframe"?. Help me to solve this sir.

Comment: to view in mobile mode add meta tags which i added in head section.

Comment: if you write code in another html page page,page render time will get increase.

Comment: so it's better to put all of those slider codes inside index.html file, isn't sir ? letter i will put those code inside my index.html

Comment: by the way does "page render time" means  code loading time to show up ?

Comment: yes, you must add bootstrap code in single page, no matter how much code you using, and keep your code in well format and should be easily readable.. page rendering time means time taken to load whole page. bootstrap is just a framework it will not take more time. if you are calling server side data you should concentrate on that. note: page should load within 9 seconds

Comment: oke, thanks for the knowledge sir. this will help me so later.

Comment: okay, please up-vote if you satisfied with my answer. thank you

Comment: i have voted your answer since your first comment sir :D. But unfortunately my voted isn't recorded :(